# Trouble proving Bezout's inequality?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $f,g\in k[X,Y]$ with respective degrees $d,e$ with $k$ algebraically closed. Suppose:

1. $f,g$ don't have a common asymptotic direction;
2. Distinct intersection points of $f,g$ have different abscissas.

Show the Bezout's inequality: The number of intersection points of $f,g$ is $\leq f,g$.

I am a bit confused on how to do this. I think that if I compute the resultant $R(y)$ it will give me a polynomial in $x$ with no repeated roots, because of $(2)$ and it will have degree $de$ because of $(1)$, now if I compute $R(x)$, it will give me a polynomial in $y$, possibly with repeated roots. The zeros of $R(x),R(y)$ will give me intersection points for the system $f=0,g=0$.

I can see that due to $(1)$, the degrees of $R(x),R(y)$ will be $de$ but I can't see why it could be smaller than $de$.

Comment: What does "asymptotic direction" mean in this context? You have a typo in the statement of the inequality. To answer your final question, did you assert that $k$ was algebraically closed?

Comment: @TedShifrin Corrected, $k$ is algebraically closed. Also, "asymptotic direction" defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Asymptotes).

Comment: @KReiser Yes. I thought about it but I guess using this, the proof would be something  like: The number of intersections is $de$ but there is this example: $y=0$ and $y=x^2$ where there is only one point of intersection, so it could be also smaller than $de$. Would that work?